# How to add wp_trash_post action after trash operation in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to add an action after the post is moved trashes. When I add an action, it runs before the main trash operation. But I want to add it after the first operation.

```
public function register_process() {
        add_action( 'wp_trash_post', [ $this, 'update_cache_custom_post_type' ], 10 );
    }

public function update_cache_custom_post_type() {
        global $post;
        if ( 'custom_post_tpe' == $post->post_type ) {
            // update cache
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the trashed_post hook, which fires after a post is sent to the trash.

http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/trashed_post/